# Showing a loading screen or a loading message when updating timeline using vis.js timeline

Tags: javascript, vis.js-timeline

I want to show a loading screen for the user when the timeline is being updated

I am using timevis library in R that is build on vis.js timeline. As I am showing quite a few points, it may take a while for the object to display and I want the user to know that.

I tried using withSpinner from shinycssloaders - and it works only up to the first time the timeline is plotted (I replot when the user changes the controls and asks for an update).

I noticed some obscure code that seems to be working in: 
https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/other/loadingScreen.html.

Couldn't find any documentation on this anywhere else.

Doesn't seem to work when I add it to my code.

````
    timevis (data = data, groups = dataGroups,
        options = list (stack   = (nrow (dataGroups) == 1),
                        orientation = list (axis = "both"),
                        loadingScreenTemplate = "function() {return '<h1>Loading...</h1>' }"))
    })```

Nothing shows up during loading. The image displays in full when done.
````

Comment: If loadingScreenTemplate  doesn't seem to work, the first thing I'd do is look when that feature was added to visjs - it's possible that it's a new feature that the timevis package doesn't have

Comment: Sound very reasonable. Unfortunately - I wasn't able to find this in documentation anywhere. How can I check the version the example is using? What is the version included in timevis? Can I update it somewho?

Comment: The only hint I found that may be related is in: https://www.changelogs.md/github/visjs/vis-timeline/ - it notes something about "Loading Screen Template" done in 5.0.0 - July 19, 2009 (very recent). Not sure if that is the thing

Comment: Yes you're on the right path. If you click on the #3537 on that line it'll take you to the commit it's referencing https://github.com/almende/vis/pull/3537 and in that commit if you look at the files changed, you'll see that indeed 'loadingScreenTemplate' was added. Timevis uses version 4.16.1 (https://github.com/daattali/timevis/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/timevis.yaml#L3) and there if you look at the issues on github you'll see there are plans to update, but unfortunately the recent version has some breaking changes so I haven't done it yet